# Doctrine php7+ type hinting, Declaration of Proxies error

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, php-7, php-7.1

I am constantly getting this weird error

```
  Warning: Declaration of Proxies\__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\MyEntity::setName(string $name): 
  AppBundle\Entity\MyEntity should be compatible with AppBundle\Entity\MyEntity::setName(?string $name): 
  AppBundle\Entity\MyEntity
```

Why on earth is this happening? Why can I not have

```
public function setName(?string $name): self
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}
```

as my setter? It works if I remove '?', but I do need it for other purpose

Comment: Usually this can be fixed by clearing the symfony cache. Did you do that already?

Comment: Have you tried with `public function setName(string $name = null): self` ?

Comment: @TobiasXy, yes, I tried with symfony command and also removing cache directory. It does not help the situation.

Comment: @yceruto, yes and it DOES help, but that is a very weird 'solution' for it is not the same construction.

Comment: What version of doctrine/common are you running? Maybe relevant: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/6203

Comment: @TobiasXy , exactly, thank you very much. Might you make an answer with this suggestion? I had run `composer update doctrine/*` and with the `doctrine/common` version 2.8, the problem was solved

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments already: According to [this issue](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/6203) older versions of doctrine/common (specifically older than 2.7.1) might have problems creating a matching proxy class if you are using optional parameter type hints.

Updating doctrine/common seems to fix the problem.